# Trying to use urllib with headers but I keep on getting this error: TypeError: a float is required. I'm using python 3.4

Tags: python, urllib

I have been trying to send requests using custom headers but python keeps on giving this error message, what am I getting wrong?
Here is my code together with the full response from python:

## Code

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

url = 'https://nytimes.com/'

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'
values = {'name': 'Kromanion Krank', 'location': 'Finland', 'language': 'Python'}
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('ascii')
html_str = urllib.request.urlopen(url, data, headers)
html_txt = html_str.text
print(html_txt)
```

## Output error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/fpt84/PycharmProjects/WebC/TEST.py", line 11, in <module>
    html_str = urllib.request.urlopen(url, data, headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 161, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 464, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 482, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 442, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1226, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1183, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1137, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1182, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1133, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 963, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 898, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1279, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 871, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 504, in create_connection
    sock.settimeout(timeout)
TypeError: a float is required
```

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `urllib.request.urlopen` (from https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) is:

```
urllib.request.urlopen(url, data=None, [timeout, ]*, cafile=None, capath=None, cadefault=False, context=None)
```

Your third "headers" argument is getting passed into the `timeout` argument of `urlopen`

You'll need to use a `Request` object to do what you want:

```
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data, headers)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

From your code example (I also had to modify the usage of the response)

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

url = 'https://nytimes.com/'

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'
values = {'name': 'Kromanion Krank', 'location': 'Finland', 'language': 'Python'}
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('ascii')
request = urllib.request.Request(url, data, headers)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
html_txt = resp.read().decode('UTF-8')
print(html_txt)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it helped but now when I try to print **html_txt** I get this error: **UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 21812-21813: character maps to <undefined>** Which decoding method can I use to be able to be able to print html_txt?

Comment: Hey guys!! Something just happened, I just updated to Pycharm 2016.x and my code now runs without problem. I mean the code error **UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 21812-21813: character maps to <undefined>** does not show anymore. Can someone explain why? Cause I don't understand.

Comment: The default terminal encoding for windows is cp1252 (aka charmap).  Not all UTF-8 characters are encodable in cp1252 (in fact, _most_ utf-8 characters are not encodable in cp1252).